# gVIM won't let me type a certain character

Tags: vim, plugins, keyboard

I'm a rookie VIM user. My problem is that VIM doesn't let me type the character "á" even though there's no problem with other characters specific to Magyar (Hungarian), like "ő" and "í". I have UTF-8 encoding and Dejavu Sans Mono font set and am using Windows 7. I already tried doing `:unmap á` but it only resulted in a "No such mapping" message. Thanks for any tips!

**Update**: Executing `:set keymap=magyar_utf-8` didn't make a difference. I have the mapping file named `magyar_utf-8.vim` in `$VIMRUNTIME/keymap` and the version I'm using is 7.3.
Furthermore "á" makes the cursor jump to the end of line in INSERT mode. Uppercase "Á" works as expected.

Comment: _how_ do you type the character (e.g. when using the `:unmap á` command)?

Comment: it's provided as a single key on a magyar keyboard

Comment: I know that vim translates some sequences like `<Esc>a` into accented letters. Can you make sure that you don't have *insert* mode mappings for `á`, `<Esc>a`, `<M-a>` and `<A-a>` (in terminals I saw `<Esc>a`=`<M-a>`=`<A-a>`). By the way, `unmap á` is unmapping normal, visual and operator-pending modes, you should use instead `iunmap á` to unmap this character in insert mode (I guess you have proplem with inserting it, as in normal mode unmapped á does nothing).

Comment: thanks for pointing out mapping keys in different modes. however `:iunmap á` also says "No such mapping".

Comment: `:imap á` says: `i á *@<End>`, but `:iunmap á` says `No such mapping`. I checked the table of digraphs here: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/digraph.html but I get the same results when trying the previous commands using `a2` instead of `á`. When I run gVIM with the `-u NONE` option, the problem disappears. I wonder where this mapping is defined...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution. So for everyone who happen to use gVIM on a Hungarian system with the auto-pairs plugin, comment out `line 196` in `auto-pairs.vim` so you can type the letter `á` as you would expect.

I have auto-pairs plugin version 1.1.1 and in my file the line to be changed reads:

`execute 'inoremap <buffer> <silent> <M-a> <END>`

Answer (score 5):

Try these things:

If there is a /key/ on your keyboard for the character `á`, type this on the command line:

> `:unmap`<kbd>C-v</kbd><kbd>*(that key>*</kbd>

to see what it is recognized as.

Alternatively, find the digraph for it

```
:dig
```

Possibly, using the above found key code, map it to use the digraph (on my system the digraph is <kbd>C-k</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>)

For completeness, special keyboard layout *in general* are handled by `keymap` settings, SO has a number of posts on how to use them in combination with e.g. dvorak keyboards.

Comment: Great, that works! I didn't know about digraphs before. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you manage to get it mapped to your native keyboard layout? That would interest future stack overflow users. PS. note also the `:keymap` and `:loadkeymap` commands for non-standard keyboard layouts

Comment: Executing `:set keymap=magyar_utf-8` didn't make a difference. I have the mapping file named `magyar_utf-8.vim` in `$VIMRUNTIME/keymap` and the version I'm using is 7.3.

Comment: Thanks for reporting that. You may want to add the info to the original post, so it will be found easier (and will even feed the site search indexer for searches)

Comment: @3k- If this answer solved your question you should consider setting it to accepted.

Comment: Sure. I'm still unable to type "á" in INSERT mode though. I can use it when typing commands like `:%s/ajánlat/ajánlatok/g` for instance, but cannot when inserting.

Comment: @3k- in that case, you need to add info on your current setup (keymap, iminsert, imsearch, imdisable, imcmdline, imactivatekey). Also, I assume you have added a mapping, did you use `inoremap`? (_please add the info by editing the original question_)